# socket.io client reconnect with server automatically

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have implemented socket.io with node.js http server. The server pushes the Realtime data to the clients. I noticed a problem that when the server is restarted the client does not get data automatically means it does not reconnect automatically with the server. Please suggest the solution. My client code is as below

**client index.html**

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
    socket.on('field', function (data) {
        console.log(data); });
</script>
```

**server.js**

```
 var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
      , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
        , fs = require('fs')
    app.listen(8070);
    var mysocket = 0;
    
    function handler(req, res)
    {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
      });
    }
    
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('index.html connected');
      mysocket = socket;
    });
    
    //udp server on 41181
    var dgram = require("dgram");
    var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
    server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
        console.log("msg: " + msg);
             if (mysocket != 0){
                 mysocket.emit('field', "" + msg);
                 }
    });
    
    server.on("listening", function () {
      var address = server.address();
      console.log("udp server listening " + address.address + ":" +      
      address.port);
    });
    server.bind(41181);
```

Comment: Add your server code here as well.

Comment: @v1shva  i have added the server